# HTML 5 Playing Video Work with .txt but not .mp4

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, mime-types

I am trying to use html5 to play video from apache on my Ubuntu 16.04 server.
The issue is if I use .mp4 extension it will not load however if I use .txt as an extension it works fine.

I have tried adding mp4 to the mime/types with .htaccess with no luck

Doesn't Work

```
<video src="video.mp4" controls=""> </video>
```

Works

```
<video src="video.txt" controls=""> </video>
```

Error from Console

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

Comment: Is there an error in the console ?

Comment: What happens if you go to the mp4 directly in your website file path? e.g http://example.com/pages/video.mp4?

Comment: I edited the question to show the error from the console. If I access the file directly it says site cannot be reached.